# why rsync not working in bash?

Tags: bash, rsync

I've got real simple rsync bash file looking like this :

```
#!bin/bash
rsync -avh --exclude={"/media/*","/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/lost+found/*"}  / /my/backup/path
```

but the problem is when i do :

```
sh mybash.sh
```

It forgot that i have some excluding to do and it backup every thing. the funniest of all is when i do :

```
rsync -avh --exclude={"/media/*","/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/lost+found/*"}  / /my/backup/path
```

In command line it consider my exclusion.

I need to put the bash in crontab but for this reason i can't.

Any help would be appreciated.

My OS is Debian wheezy.

Comment: Does `sh -c 'echo {1,2,3}'` output `1 2 3` or `{1,2,3}`? You should be using `bash mybash.sh`, even if you are sure that `sh` is actually `bash`.

Comment: it out put :{1,2,3} , okey let me test the bash.

Comment: The hashbang line is off: `#!bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: The output of `{1,2,3}` means that `sh` is not a link or copy of `bash`, but some other shell, probably `dash`.

Comment: @chepner , it seems to be working with bash, make it to an answer to accept.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks , nice tip.

Comment: ...but calling it with `sh mybash.sh` overrides the hashbang line anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I wish i could choose two correct answer but i can't. although i should thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the script with something other than `bash`, probably `dash`, which doesn't recognize brace expansion. Be explicit:

```
bash mybash.sh
```

However, brace expansion in `bash` is primarily meant as a shortcut for interactive use. If you are writing a script, just be explicit (your text editor should make it simple):

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -avh \
   --exclude "/media/*" \
   --exclude "/dev/*" \
   --exclude "/proc/*" \
   --exclude "/sys/*" \
   --exclude "/tmp/*" \
   --exclude "/run/*" \
   --exclude "/mnt/*" \
   --exclude "/lost+found/*" \
   / /my/backup/path
```

Now you don't need to worry about which shell executes the script, as long as it is POSIX compliant.

If you really want to use `bash` features, I recommend using an array instead of brace expansion. It's more readable and easier to edit in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash
exclusions=(
   --exclude "/media/*"
   --exclude "/dev/*"
   --exclude "/proc/*"
   --exclude "/sys/*"
   --exclude "/tmp/*"
   --exclude "/run/*"
   --exclude "/mnt/*"
   --exclude "/lost+found/*"
)
rsync -avh "${exclusions[@]}" / /my/backup/path
```